# Using Zabbix with Active Agent, How to determine the correct key. (LLD)

Tags: zabbix

I'm trying to do a discovery to get info from antivirus software.

In zabbix_agentd.conf i put this:

```
UserParameter=custom.discovery, cscript c:\soft\zabbix\av.vbs //NOLOGO
```

With this result:

```
{"data":[
{"{#DISPLAYNAME}": "ESET Endpoint Security 6.4.2014.2",
"{#PRODUCTSTATE}": "266240",
"{#TIMESTAMP}": "Tue, 18 Jul 2017 21:24:26 GMT"},
{"{#DISPLAYNAME}": "Windows Defender",
"{#PRODUCTSTATE}": "393472",
"{#TIMESTAMP}": "Thu, 10 Nov 2016 12:20:52 GMT"}
]}
```

My Discovery rule is this:

```
Name: Antivirus
Type: Zabbix Agent (Active)
key: custom.discovery
```

And i create this item prototype:

```
Name: Antivirus {#DISPLAYNAME}
Type: Zabbix Agent (Active)
Key: custom.discovery[ {#DISPLAYNAME}, PRODUCTSTATE]
```

My problem is when the item trying to get the "Productstate", the items are discovered correctly, but without value.

At the Configuration/Host/Item, i see the error "Item does not allow parameters" in each item created from the discovery.

Somebody can help me? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have separate userparameter to get item values, and that key should be used in the item prototypes. Your LLD rule key should not return item values.

Comment: Finally, I have used a calculated type prototype, with the formula {#PRODUCTSTATE}. But I think your solution is more correct.